# Unknown column '' in 'field list' in mysql vb.net

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to display data from mysql database but the problem is nothing appears on the datagridview.

For further explanation please take a look at the picture in the link below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAY0M.png

In my code, I tried to combine the sql header and datagridview header but still it doesn't work.

```
    Public Sub subj_table()
        dbDataSet.Clear()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dbDataSet

        Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim bSource As New BindingSource

        Try
           MysqlConn.Open()
           Dim Query As String

           Query = "SELECT subject_code.subjCode, description.desc, units.units FROM enrollmentdb.subject"

           COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)

           SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
           Try
              SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
           Catch ex As Exception

           End Try

           bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
           DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
           SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()

    DataGridView1.Columns("Subject Code").DataPropertyName = "subjCode"
    DataGridView1.Columns("Description").DataPropertyName = "desc"
    DataGridView1.Columns("Units").DataPropertyName = "units" 

   MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose() 
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: can you add your data base table structure

Comment: this is an issue with your SQL query

Comment: @Guide Me - Is there some reason you didn't provide the MySql table structures? As Mahesh says, the problem is with your Sql query. Also, if the column names have dots in them, you'll need to put backticks or double quotes around them, otherwise MySql will try to interpret as `tablename.columnname`. I.e. it will interpret `subject_code.subjCode` as column `subjCode` belonging to table `subject_code`. Did you catch the exception in the debugger? I suspect it will identify that problem.

Comment: I added this one but still it doesn't work. `DataGridView1.Columns("Subject Code").DataPropertyName = "subjCode"` `DataGridView1.Columns("Description").DataPropertyName = "desc"` `DataGridView1.Columns("Units").DataPropertyName = "units"`